# Stock iOS camera app seems to have wider field of view

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

I'm working on a video app for iOS, and everything seems to work fine other than if we go into stock iPhone camera app the field of view seems wider. I've tried playing with the different AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer gravity settings (AVLayerVideoGravityResize, AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect and AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill) to no avail.

In fact, using other camera apps (like when taking a photo in Facebook) we get a much more similar output than we do with the stock camera app.

Does anyone have any information on why something like this might be? I've been scouring the internet and haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the resolution of the still image camera is different then the resolution of the video camera, see for instance https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3490649?tstart=0